# using the Starts-with fuction correctly

Tags: xslt, startswith

Below is the XSLT used to trigger and email

I need the email to send out when either the Event Form or a product beginning with the word presentation is ordered.

Currently when i order the event from the email is sent out but if i order a presentation the email does not send, I am assuming it is because i have not used the Starts-with fucntion correctly

Can anyone see the issue?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
  <xsl:output method="html" />
  <xsl:variable name="DateOrderSubmitted" select="//Sqls/OrderProduct/Row/DateOrderSubmitted" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:if test="//Sqls/OrderProduct/Row/ProductName != 'Event Form' and //Sqls/OrderProduct/Row/ProductName != starts-with(ProductName, 'Presentation')">
      <xsl:message terminate="yes">
Error: email terminated by xsl test
</xsl:message>
    </xsl:if>
Hello,<br />
    <br />
The output file of order product # can be downloaded <a>
    <xsl:attribute name="href">http://www.cpiyourway.co.uk/uStore/Controls/SDK/OrderOutputProxy.ashx?token=<xsl:value-of select="//Sqls/OrderProduct/Row/OutputToken" />
    </xsl:attribute>here</a> (when available).
</xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show a sample of your input XML? Thank you

Comment: Sorry Tim, not sure what you mean, This is set up on ustore an xmpie software

Comment: As XSLT is used to transform XML into another format (HTML in this case), you need to know what the XML looks like before you can write any XSLT. How did you know to write `Sqls/OrderProduct/Row/ProductName` for example?

Comment: It was already supplied, i am just trying to change the code I was supplied with to allow foe new products

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: **[mcve]**.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give a precise answer without seeing the XML, but instead of writing this...

```
//Sqls/OrderProduct/Row/ProductName != starts-with(ProductName, 'Presentation')
```

The syntax you probably want is this

```
//Sqls/OrderProduct/Row[not(starts-with(ProductName, 'Presentation'))]
```

However, you full expression is also checking for "EventName" so the two expression really need to be combined into one, like so:

```
<xsl:if test="//Sqls/OrderProduct/Row[ProductName != 'Event Form' and not(starts-with(ProductName, 'Presentation'))]">
```

**EDIT:** Or perhaps you need this, depending on what logic you are trying to implement

```
<xsl:if test="not(//Sqls/OrderProduct/Row[ProductName = 'Event Form' or starts-with(ProductName, 'Presentation')])">
```

Comment: Hi Tim This did not work, any other suggestions? or can you not suggest anything else as i cannot supply the XML?

Comment: I've added an edit to my answer, although it is a bit of a guess without seeing the XML.

Comment: Until OP obliges the request to add XML and thus a proper [mcve], this is as good of an answer as is possible -- more generous than deserved, imo.